# Debian mirror syncing error

Tags: debian, freebsd, rsync, mirror

I'm running the Debian mirror syncing tool 'ftpsync' on a FreeBSD 8.2 system. I changed the script a bit only to adapt to the FreeBSD system (e.g., path of bash). And I followed the steps from http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror to setup the mirror site.

The script is put in the cron job and will be run everyday. From time to time, I see the following error message in the log files which looks like:

```
file has vanished: "/pool/main/g/gcc-snapshot/.gcc-snapshot_20120625-1_s390x.deb.1cqlSA" (in debian)
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1518) [generator=3.0.9]
```

If this error occurs, two files starting with '`Archive-Update-in-Progress-`' and '`Archive-Update-Required`' will appear in the mirror repository.
It seems that some files have been updated during the syncing from the upstream. If I run the 'ftpsync' script again by hand, both files will disappear and the issue will be resolved.

Do you have  any idea on how to get rid of this problem other than running the script again manually? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap ftpsync in a shellscript like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ftpsync
while [ -f /pool/main/Archive-Update-In-Progress ]; do
   sleep 600
   ftpsync
done
```

This will update the repo until the Archive-Update on the other side is done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: You can't! Only if you know what these files look like, you will be able to exclude them from the rsync call.

It seems that those files are temporary ones and disappear during the file transfer.